# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta a mongoatlas a través del id de un registro?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, sql, nosql

Lo que quiero realizar es una consulta a mongo atlas en dónde me filtre los resultados según un id que se envíe por parámetros, sin embargo, aunque envíe el id por parámetros este no encuentra el registro en la base de datos y retorna un json vacío aún sabiendo que el registro existe . Dejo parte del código que vengo trabajando.

```
GetUserById(id){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            client.connect().then(cli=>{
                console.log(id);
                const collection=client.db("Database-Reme").collection("users");
                collection.find({cedula:id},{projection:{_id:0,"Contraseña":0}}).toArray(function(err,result){
                    if (err) reject(err);
                    resolve(result);
                });
            }).catch(err=>{
                return responseMessage.RequestAlert(400,"No se ha podido generar la consulta","GET");            })
        })
    }
    async AuxById(id){
        let u;
        const info=await this.GetUserById(id).then(a=>{
            u=a
        })
        const message=responseMessage.RequestData(200,"Consulta exitosa","GET",u);
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: He logrado solucionar mi problema, mi error era que yo estaba mandando el id del usuario como string mientras en la base de datos estaba como entero

Answer (score 1):

Usas promesas o async/await, pero no combines ambos.

```
async AuxById(id){
    try{
        const info = await this.GetUserById(id);
        const message = responseMessage.RequestData(200,"Consulta exitosa","GET",info);
        return message;
    }
    catch(e){
        // Handle the error
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas amigo, lo tendré en cuenta